# AD auth group changes not reflacting

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-authentication, passport-azure-ad

I am using node js passport-azure-ad with OIDCStrategy.

When i removed a user from a group it is not reflating on my code

```
req.user._json.groups[0]
```

returning all the group including removed group.

But when i tried and restarted my node js server group removed.

How can i force to update groups without restarting node js server ? Is this due to the token caching ? How can i refresh token in passport-azure-ad.

I tried to search how can i refresh token in passport-azure-ad but nothing found related to this.

Comment: Don't know how to refresh the token, but it absolutely has to do with it :) Since the group ids are in the access token (assuming you set `groupMembershipClaims` in the app manifest), they will be in token cache until the token is refreshed. Typically access tokens last only 1 hour though. The groups should not be there if passport (or another component) uses the refresh token to get new tokens. Is it a huge problem if the groups remain there until the token expires?

Comment: Yes this is a huge problem. My whole dashboard depends on group access and ad auth. If i remove user from the group user not able to access dashboard for that group.

Comment: That is a general problem with JSON Web Tokens. Since the token will be "valid" even if the user is deleted entirely until the token expires. One solution I can think of would be to set expiry times for tokens to a smaller duration. You can find info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes.

Answer (score 0):

Check claims in access token will not be reliable in your scenario . Instead, you could call graph api to check whether user is inside a group . You could use microsoft graph api to get the groups that the user is a direct member of :

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/getMemberGroups
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 33

{
  "securityEnabledOnly": true
}
```

Or you could use azure ad graph api : Call the [isMemberOf function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ad/graph/api/functions-and-actions#isMemberOf) on the directory service to check whether a specified user, group, contact, or service principal is a member of a specified group.